# Automatización compilación de Python 3

Tags: python

Tengo una duda complicada, necesito saber si alguno de ustedes sabe como poder trabajarla.

Lo que pasa es qué tengo una base de datos muy grande (planilla CSV), que tiene alrededor de 45 mil filas. Para esto programé un desarrollo que cuenta elementos repetidos en relación a fechas de estos, de esta forma, varios elementos repetidos se consideran como historias, donde una historia se acaba cuando ocurre un repetido después de 30 días (para esto hice un diccionario).

Cada día se agrega nueva información a la base de datos (nuevas filas al CSV), por lo que compilar todo la hace muy lento. Me gustaría correr el archivo completo una vez, y luego este se compile (el día siguiente) desde donde quedó compilado el día anterior, o sea considerando historias que se puedan seguir trabajando.

Mi duda es si en Python es posible tener un código con memoria donde se considere lo de ayer para trabajar hoy.

Gracias!!

Comment: Había pensado en correr la base de datos completa una vez en mi código, y luego tener otro código igual que se ejecute cada día relacionado a una planilla desde cero. El problema es que esta planilla de este cero igual se irá llenando y al final tendré 2 bases de datos muy grandes.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "compilar"? Lo de ayer se puede usar para trabajar hoy siempre que esté guardado en algún dispositivo de almacenamiento.

Comment: Tienes muchas formas de dotar de *"persistencia"* a los objetos en python, desde guardar la información en una base datos como [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) a crear ficheros [*pickle*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Pero no hay nada qué hacer para evitar que se te acumulen los datos recopilados diariamente. Tendrás que pensar en cómo pasar historias a un fichero pasivo para agilizar el proceso.

Comment: Interesante pregunta. Este finde le echo un ojo, aunque probablemente se me adelanet alguien. Pero nos harían falta más detalles, que concretes el problema. Si pudieses poner un ejemplo reducido de tu código y un fichero CSV también reducido que de una idea de lo que haces sería ideal.

Comment: Deberias intentar aclarar que es a lo que te refieres con "compilar". Si lo que quieres es que al ejecutar el script sin que lea/trabaje datos ya procesados bastaría con guardar la última línea procesada y leer a partir de ahí. También puedes guardar el "estado" de tu programa usando serialización con pickle como comenta Chema y reanudarlo posteriormente. Ten en cuenta que dejar crecer un fichero sin límite va a terminaar generandote algo inmanejable. Deberias aportar más información, para poder abordar el problema.

Comment: Un punto importante es saber si los datos ya procesados van a hacer falta en alguna medida para los nuevos calculos. Por lo que insinuas parece ser que así es, es decir, los nuevos datos pueden añadirse a grupos formados con datos de dias anteriores. Esto debes manejarlo de ser así, pero poco podemos ayudar sin conocer la implementación. Saludos.

Comment: con compilar te refieres a leer todos los datos? cuando son muchos datos puedes resolver el problema realizando una redistribución de estos en la base de datos ( una nueva formalización ) que te permita separar los registros, lo que facilita el proceso de carga. otra cosa que puedes hacer es estudiar la relación que pueden tener los futuros datos de forma que puedas formalizar una consulta más eficiente. Pero es necesaria un poco más de información para ayudarte. puedes abstraer las entidades y sus relaciones para mostrarlas de forma que podamos ayudarte con la solución.

Comment: En definitiva, exporto un archivo con la información que compila en el día, el cual leo al día siguiente, de esta forma continuo con las historias sin necesidad de correr el archivo completo.